# Exception Conditions: Incorrect Exception thrown

Tags: java, exception

I'm having an issue with a homework assignment of mine. We have our assignments graded by a website online and I keep receiving the following error about the code I have displayed below.

**Error:**

```
Exception conditions. Incorrect exception thrown for null a.java.lang.NullPointerException
```

```
  public static int[] nearestK(int[] a, int val, int k) {

  int x = 0;

  if (k < x || a.length == 0 || a == null)
  {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("k is not invalid");
  }

  if (k == 0 || k > a.length) 
  {
     int[] incorrect = new int[0];
     return incorrect ;
  }

  final int value = val; 
  Integer[] copy = new Integer[a.length]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
     copy[i] = a[i];
  }

  Arrays.sort(copy, 
        new Comparator<Integer>() {                   
           @Override
           public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
              int distance1 = Math.abs(value - o1); 
              int distance2 = Math.abs(value - o2); 
              return Integer.compare(distance1, distance2);
           }
        });

  int[] answer = new int[k]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
     answer[i] = copy[i];
  }

  return answer;

}
```

Comment: You need to check if `a` is null before attempting to access its `length` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is failing:

```
if (k < x || a.length == 0 || a == null)
```

because `a.length` will throw a NullPointerException before it gets a chance to check `a == null`.

Try changing it to:

```
if (a == null || k < x || a.length == 0)
```

so the null is checked first.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (k < x || a.length == 0 || a == null)
```

This needs to be the other way around, because it is evaluated left-to-right, and the null check needs to guard the length check.

As it is, `a.length` produces a null pointer exception.

```
  if (k < x || a == null || a.length == 0)
```

With this sequence, evaluation will not go all the way to the right (that is what the short-circuiting operator `||` does).

Comment: I switched those around and now have the new error of:
Exception conditions. Did not throw required exception for zero-length array.